# How to get rough boundaries to classify colors into named colors?

Tags: algorithm, colors

I got a list of ~150 CSS colors which have a name mapped to a hex code. I then used the [`nearest-color`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nearest-color) JS library to calculate the "nearest" color. From it's docs, this is how it works:

> Finding the nearest color is a specific case of the "nearest neighbor search" (or NNS) problem. The predefined colors can be thought of as points in 3D space where the X, Y, and Z axes represent each color's red, green, and blue (RGB) values. So finding the nearest color to any given value amounts to finding the closet neighbor to the point where that color would reside when plotted in such a 3D space.

It works pretty well for some colors, but not others. I manually gathered more color names, for a total of ~500 colors with names, and it gets better, but it still misses some, such as these. It calls the first one "medium slate blue", but I would just say that is a shade of "purple". It calls the next one "inchworm", a random meaningless name from my list IMO, but I would call it "yellow-green".

[image]

[image]

It does a pretty good job on this next example, which it calls salmon. You could even get more general and say red or red-orange.

[image]

How can I improve on this? The "distance" algorithm approach doesn't seem to work if you have a list of 15 basic colors mapped to a single hex code, it makes all kinds of mistakes (it was calling all light colors "pink" for me, which is why I greatly expanded the list of named colors).

Is there an easy way to draw a boundary around the colors in a color picker sort of thing, and get out the bounded points for the color space? And then check if the color is within that 2D surface area? That seems complex, but perhaps someone made a system like that. Or if not, is there any other way to improve on this distance solution, to make it name the colors more accurately?

In the end, I would really like to pick like 10 colors (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, brown, black, white, gray), and have it find the closest approximate given some input color. But that seems pretty unsolvable to me at this point, unless I did the impossible brute-force approach and named each and every pixel of the color space its corresponding value (and it would get hard at the rough "boundaries").

I get that this is subjective too, but is there any way to make a better system than what I have so far? This question doesn't need any code (I did it in JavaScript), it would be helpful to just have an explanation of a better approach in general.

Here is my rough code if it helps:

```
import getNearestColor from 'nearest-color'

const baseColors = {
  Red: "#FF0000",
  "Cherry red": "#990F02",
  Rose: "#E3242B",
  Jam: "#60100B",
  Merlot: "#541E1B",
  Garnet: "#610C04",
  Crimson: "#DC143C",
  Ruby: "#900603",
  Scarlet: "#900D09",
  Wine: "#4E0707",
  Brick: "#7E2811",
  Apple: "#A91B0D",
  Mahogany: "#420C09",
  Blood: "#710C04",
  "Sangria red": "#5E1916",
  Berry: "#7A1712",
  Currant: "#680C07",
  "Blush red": "#BC544B",
  Candy: "#D21404",
  Lipstick: "#9B1003",
  Carmine: "#960018",
  "Persian red": "#CA3433",
  Vermilion: "#7E191B",
  "Imperial red": "#ED2939",
  "Chili red": "#C21807",
  Maroon: "#800000",
  "Fire brick": "#B22222",
  Desire: "#EA3C53",
  Raspberry: "#D21F3C",
  "Candy apple": "#FF0800",
  Hibiscus: "#B43757",
  "U.s. flag": "#BF0A30",
  Ferrari: "#FF2800",
  "Dark red": "#8B0000",
  "Prismatic red": "#D03D33",
  "49ers red": "#AA0000",
  "Cardinals red": "#BD2031",
  "Ajax red": "#D2122E",
  "Alabama crimson": "#9E1B32",
  "Alizarin crimson": "#E32636",
  "Amaranth red": "#F4364C",
  "American rose": "#FF033E",
  "Angels red": "#BA0021",
  "Arsenal red": "#DB0007",
  "Auburn red": "#A52A2A",
  "Bu scarlet": "#CC0000",
  "Bills red": "#C60C30",
  "Bittersweet shimmer": "#BF4F51",
  Orange: "#FFA500",
  Tangerine: "#FA8128",
  Merigold: "#FCAE1E",
  Cider: "#B56727",
  Rust: "#8D4004",
  Ginger: "#BE5504",
  Tiger: "#FC6A03",
  Fire: "#DD571C",
  Bronze: "#B2560D",
  Cantaloupe: "#FDA172",
  Apricot: "#ED820E",
  Clay: "#80400B",
  Honey: "#EC9706",
  Carrot: "#ED7117",
  Squash: "#C95B0C",
  Spice: "#7A3803",
  Marmalade: "#D16002",
  Amber: "#893101",
  Sandstone: "#D67229",
  Yam: "#CC5801",
  Tangelo: "#FC4C02",
  Flame: "#E34A27",
  Fulvous: "#E68000",
  "Dark orange": "#FF8C00",
  "Vivid orange": "#FF5E0E",
  "Orange-red": "#FF4500",
  "Metallic orange": "#E26310",
  Pumpkin: "#F5761A",
  "Smashed pumpkin": "#FD673A",
  "International orange": "#FF4F00",
  "Spanish orange": "#F06105",
  "Princeton orange": "#FF8F00",
  "Deep saffron": "#FFA52C",
  "Alloy orange": "#C35214",
  "Halloween orange": "#EE5921",
  Gamboge: "#E89611",
  "Medium vermilion": "#CF5B2E",
  "Pastel orange": "#FEBA4F",
  "Philippine orange": "#F26E01",
  "Royal orange": "#FF9944",
  Coral: "#FF7F50",
  "Dark coral": "#D75341",
  "Cadmium orange": "#E6812F",
  Rajah: "#FABA5F",
  "Mango tango": "#FB8842",
  "Orange peel": "#FF9F00",
  "Vivid tangelo": "#EC7625",
  Persimmon: "#EC5800",
  "Browns orange": "#FF3C00",
  "Burnt orange": "#CC5500",
  Green: "#008000",
  Chartreuse: "#7FFF00",
  Juniper: "#3A5311",
  Sage: "#728C69",
  Lime: "#00FF00",
  Fern: "#5DBB63",
  Olive: "#808000",
  Emerald: "#028A0F",
  Pear: "#74B72E",
  Moss: "#466D1D",
  Shamrock: "#03AC13",
  Seafoam: "#3DED97",
  Pine: "#234F1E",
  Parakeet: "#03C04A",
  Mint: "#99EDC3",
  Seaweed: "#354A21",
  Pickle: "#597D35",
  Pistachio: "#B2D3C2",
  Basil: "#32612D",
  Crocodile: "#607D3B",
  Amazon: "#3B7A57",
  Avocado: "#568203",
  Celadon: "#ACE1AF",
  "Forest green": "#228B22",
  "Hunter green": "#3F704D",
  "Artichoke green": "#8F9779",
  "Jungle green": "#29AB87",
  "Tropical rainforest": "#00755E",
  "Persian green": "#00A693",
  "Sea green": "#2E8B57",
  "Jade green": "#00A86B",
  "Laurel green": "#A9BA9D",
  "Army green": "#4B5320",
  "Kelly green": "#4CBB17",
  "Paris green": "#50C878",
  "Pakistan green": "#006600",
  Spring: "#00F0A8",
  Chateau: "#48A860",
  Swamp: "#A8C090",
  Mantis: "#74C365",
  Fun: "#007848",
  Viridian: "#609078",
  "Reseda green": "#6C7C59",
  Verdun: "#487800",
  "Castleton green": "#00563B",
  "Bottle green": "#006A4E",
  "Cadmium green": "#006B3C",
  "Camouflage green": "#78866B",
  "Dollar bill": "#85BB65",
  Inchworm: "#B2EC5D",
  Blue: "#0000FF",
  Slate: "#757C88",
  Sky: "#63C5DA",
  Navy: "#000080",
  Indigo: "#4B0082",
  Cobalt: "#1338BE",
  Teal: "#008080",
  Ocean: "#016064",
  Peacock: "#022D36",
  Azure: "#F0FFFF",
  Cerulean: "#0492C2",
  Lapis: "#2832C2",
  Spruce: "#2C3E4C",
  Stone: "#59788E",
  Aegean: "#1F456E",
  Blueberry: "#241571",
  Denim: "#151E3D",
  Admiral: "#051094",
  Sapphire: "#52B2BF",
  Arctic: "#82EEFD",
  Turquoise: "#40E0D0",
  Steel: "#4682B4",
  "B'dazzled": "#2E5894",
  "Powder blue": "#B0E0E6",
  "Us air force academy blue": "#004F98",
  "Baby blue": "#89CFF0",
  "Beau blue": "#BCD4E6",
  "Little boy blue": "#6CA0DC",
  "Tiffany blue": "#81D8D0",
  "Carolina blue": "#4B9CD3",
  "Turkish blue": "#4F97A3",
  "Maya blue": "#73C2FB",
  "Cornflower blue": "#6495ED",
  "Blue sapphire": "#126180",
  "Egyptian blue": "#1034A6",
  "Yale blue": "#00356B",
  "Space cadet": "#1D2951",
  "Imperial blue": "#005A92",
  "Ruddy blue": "#76ABDF",
  "Air superiority blue": "#72A0C1",
  "Aquamarine blue": "#6BCAE2",
  "Argentina blue": "#6CB4EE",
  "Astros navy": "#002D62",
  "Bayern blue": "#0066B2",
  "Berry blue": "#4F86F7",
  "Blue yonder": "#5072A7",
  "Bleu de france": "#318CE7",
  "Blue-gray": "#6699CC",
  "Boeing blue": "#0039A6",
  "Braves navy": "#13274F",
  Purple: "#800080",
  Mauve: "#7A4988",
  "Dark violet": "#9400D3",
  Boysenberry: "#630436",
  "Electric lavender": "#E39FF6",
  Plum: "#DDA0DD",
  "Strong magenta": "#A1045A",
  "Deep lilac": "#B65FCF",
  Grape: "#663046",
  "Royal periwinkle": "#BE93D4",
  "Sangria purple": "#4D0F28",
  Eggplant: "#311432",
  "Jazzberry jam": "#67032F",
  Iris: "#9867C5",
  Heather: "#9E7BB5",
  Amethyst: "#A45EE5",
  Raisin: "#290916",
  "Medium orchid": "#BA55D3",
  "Dark mulberry": "#4C0121",
  "Deep wine": "#2C041C",
  Thistle: "#D8BFD8",
  Orchid: "#DA70D6",
  "Electric violet": "#8F00FF",
  "Medium purple": "#9370DB",
  "Dark orchid": "#9932CC",
  "Dark magenta": "#8B008B",
  Veronica: "#A020F0",
  Heliotrope: "#DF73FF",
  Purpureus: "#9A4EAE",
  "Northwestern purple": "#4E2A84",
  "Ksu purple": "#512888",
  "Pomp and power": "#86608E",
  "Mardi gras": "#880085",
  Eminence: "#6C3082",
  "Pansy purple": "#78184A",
  Palatinate: "#72246C",
  "Dark purple": "#301934",
  Byzantium: "#702963",
  "English violet": "#563C5C",
  Affair: "#6F4685",
  "Long distance": "#6F456E",
  "Prince charming": "#493F5E",
  "Lipstick stain": "#8E4785",
  Pompadour: "#720058",
  "Grape color": "#6F2DA8",
  "Pizza edge": "#9A2CA0",
  "Tyrian purple": "#66023C",
  "Ultra violet": "#645394",
  "Electric purple": "#BF00FF",
  Studio: "#7851A9",
  "Brown oil": "#231709",
  "Roasted coffee": "#4B371C",
  Mocha: "#3C280D",
  "Peanut brown": "#795C34",
  Carob: "#362511",
  Hickory: "#371D10",
  Wood: "#3F301D",
  Pecan: "#4A2511",
  Walnut: "#432616",
  Caramel: "#65350F",
  Gingerbread: "#5E2C04",
  Syrup: "#481F01",
  "Dark chocolate": "#2E1503",
  Tortilla: "#9A7B4F",
  Umber: "#352315",
  Tawny: "#80471C",
  Brunette: "#3B1E08",
  "Cinnamon brown": "#652A0E",
  Penny: "#532915",
  "Cedar brown": "#4A3728",
  Beaver: "#9F8170",
  Bistre: "#3D2B1F",
  Bole: "#79443B",
  "Burnt umber": "#8A3324",
  "Cafe au lait": "#A67B5B",
  "Cafe noir": "#4B3621",
  Coffee: "#6F4E37",
  "Deep coffee": "#704241",
  Copper: "#B87333",
  "Dark brown": "#654321",
  Taupe: "#483C32",
  Ecru: "#C2B280",
  "Golden brown": "#996515",
  Khaki: "#F0E68C",
  Ochre: "#CC7722",
  "Light brown": "#B5651D",
  "Saddle brown": "#8B4513",
  Russet: "#80461B",
  Sienna: "#A0522D",
  "Antique brass": "#CD9575",
  Burlywood: "#DEB887",
  Peru: "#CD853F",
  Tumbleweed: "#DEAA88",
  "Dark vanilla": "#D1BEA8",
  "Wood brown": "#C19A6B",
  Chamoisee: "#A0785A",
  Deer: "#BA8759",
  Dirt: "#9B7653",
  Coconut: "#965A3E",
  "Windsor tan": "#A75502",
  Black: "#000000",
  Ebony: "#080402",
  Crow: "#0D0907",
  Charcoal: "#28231D",
  Midnight: "#040406",
  Ink: "#070504",
  Raven: "#050301",
  Oil: "#050100",
  Grease: "#0A0806",
  Onyx: "#030104",
  Pitch: "#030001",
  Soot: "#160D08",
  Sable: "#060606",
  "Jet black": "#030303",
  Coal: "#0C0908",
  Metal: "#0E0C0A",
  Obsidian: "#020403",
  Jade: "#000302",
  Spider: "#040200",
  Leather: "#0B0705",
  Asphalt: "#0C0404",
  Licorice: "#1A1110",
  Night: "#0C090A",
  "Charleston green": "#232B2B",
  "Dark jungle green": "#1A2421",
  "Eerie black": "#1B1B1B",
  "Raisin black": "#242124",
  "Smoky black": "#100C08",
  "Black rock": "#010127",
  "Neutral black": "#0B0B0B",
  "Black denim": "#191C27",
  "Vampire black": "#0F0404",
  "Cool black": "#151922",
  "Frost black": "#191C20",
  "Power black": "#0E0C01",
  "Premium black": "#100E09",
  "Black magic": "#0B0510",
  "Alien black": "#1A2228",
  "Black chocolate": "#1B1811",
  "Gothic grape": "#120321",
  Metropolis: "#1A1A1A",
  "Night shadow": "#1C1C1C",
  "Dark raisin": "#1A0F0F",
  "Tea bag": "#161311",
  "Tech black": "#0D0E0E",
  "Dull black": "#161616",
  "Dark black": "#010203",
  "Natural black": "#07000B",
  "Retro black": "#1F201F",
  "Deep black": "#050203",
  Gray: "#808080",
  Shadow: "#373737",
  Graphite: "#594D5B",
  Iron: "#322D31",
  Pewter: "#696880",
  Cloud: "#C5C6D0",
  Silver: "#C0C0C0",
  Smoke: "#59515E",
  "Dark slate": "#3E3D53",
  Anchor: "#41424C",
  Ash: "#564C4D",
  Porpoise: "#4D4C5C",
  Dove: "#7C6E7F",
  Fog: "#655967",
  Flint: "#7F7D9C",
  "Charcoal gray": "#232023",
  Pebble: "#333333",
  Lead: "#3F3F4E",
  Coin: "#9897A9",
  Fossil: "#787276",
  Arsenic: "#3B444B",
  Nevada: "#666A6D",
  Scorpion: "#5E5E5E",
  "Battleship gray": "#848482",
  "Carbon gray": "#625D5D",
  "Davy's gray": "#555555",
  "Dim gray": "#696969",
  "Gray cloud": "#B6B6B4",
  "Gray dolphin": "#5C5858",
  "Gray wolf": "#504A4B",
  Gunmetal: "#2A3439",
  Marengo: "#4C5866",
  "Medium gray": "#BEBEBE",
  Nickel: "#727472",
  "Stone gray": "#928E85",
  "Outer space": "#414A4C",
  "Rocket metallic": "#8A7F8D",
  "Silver chalice": "#ACACAC",
  "Smokey gray": "#726E6D",
  "Sonic gray": "#757575",
  "Spanish gray": "#989898",
  "Taupe gray": "#8B8589",
  "Vampire gray": "#565051",
  "X11 gray": "#BBBCB6",
  "Dark silver": "#746D69",
  "Pastel gray": "#CCCDC6",
  "Misty gray": "#BCC2C2",
  "Vintage gray": "#989692",
  "Zombie gray": "#63645E",
  "Perfect gray": "#A1A1A1",
  "Alice blue": "#F0F8FF",
  "Antique white": "#FAEBD7",
  Aqua: "#00FFFF",
  Aquamarine: "#7FFFD4",
  Beige: "#F5F5DC",
  Bisque: "#FFE4C4",
  "Blanched almond": "#FFEBCD",
  "Blue violet": "#8A2BE2",
  Brown: "#A52A2A",
  "Burly wood": "#DEB887",
  "Cadet blue": "#5F9EA0",
  Chocolate: "#D2691E",
  Cornsilk: "#FFF8DC",
  Cyan: "#00FFFF",
  "Dark blue": "#00008B",
  "Dark cyan": "#008B8B",
  "Dark golden rod": "#B8860B",
  "Dark gray": "#A9A9A9",
  "Dark green": "#006400",
  "Dark grey": "#A9A9A9",
  "Dark khaki": "#BDB76B",
  "Dark olive green": "#556B2F",
  "Dark salmon": "#E9967A",
  "Dark sea green": "#8FBC8F",
  "Dark slate blue": "#483D8B",
  "Dark slate gray": "#2F4F4F",
  "Dark slate grey": "#2F4F4F",
  "Dark turquoise": "#00CED1",
  "Deep pink": "#FF1493",
  "Deep sky blue": "#00BFFF",
  "Dim grey": "#696969",
  "Dodger blue": "#1E90FF",
  "Floral white": "#FFFAF0",
  Fuchsia: "#FF00FF",
  Gainsboro: "#DCDCDC",
  "Ghost white": "#F8F8FF",
  Gold: "#FFD700",
  "Golden rod": "#DAA520",
  "Green yellow": "#ADFF2F",
  Grey: "#808080",
  "Honey dew": "#F0FFF0",
  "Hot pink": "#FF69B4",
  "Indian red": "#CD5C5C",
  Ivory: "#FFFFF0",
  Lavender: "#E6E6FA",
  "Lavender blush": "#FFF0F5",
  "Lawn green": "#7CFC00",
  "Lemon chiffon": "#FFFACD",
  "Light blue": "#ADD8E6",
  "Light coral": "#F08080",
  "Light cyan": "#E0FFFF",
  "Light golden rod yellow": "#FAFAD2",
  "Light gray": "#D3D3D3",
  "Light green": "#90EE90",
  "Light grey": "#D3D3D3",
  "Light pink": "#FFB6C1",
  "Light salmon": "#FFA07A",
  "Light sea green": "#20B2AA",
  "Light sky blue": "#87CEFA",
  "Light slate gray": "#778899",
  "Light slate grey": "#778899",
  "Light steel blue": "#B0C4DE",
  "Light yellow": "#FFFFE0",
  "Lime green": "#32CD32",
  Linen: "#FAF0E6",
  Magenta: "#FF00FF",
  "Medium aqua marine": "#66CDAA",
  "Medium blue": "#0000CD",
  "Medium sea green": "#3CB371",
  "Medium slate blue": "#7B68EE",
  "Medium spring green": "#00FA9A",
  "Medium turquoise": "#48D1CC",
  "Medium violet red": "#C71585",
  "Midnight blue": "#191970",
  "Mint cream": "#F5FFFA",
  "Misty rose": "#FFE4E1",
  Moccasin: "#FFE4B5",
  "Navajo white": "#FFDEAD",
  "Old lace": "#FDF5E6",
  "Olive drab": "#6B8E23",
  "Orange red": "#FF4500",
  "Pale golden rod": "#EEE8AA",
  "Pale green": "#98FB98",
  "Pale turquoise": "#AFEEEE",
  "Pale violet red": "#DB7093",
  "Papaya whip": "#FFEFD5",
  "Peach puff": "#FFDAB9",
  Pink: "#FFC0CB",
  "Rebecca purple": "#663399",
  "Rosy brown": "#BC8F8F",
  "Royal blue": "#4169E1",
  Salmon: "#FA8072",
  "Sandy brown": "#F4A460",
  "Sea shell": "#FFF5EE",
  "Sky blue": "#87CEEB",
  "Slate blue": "#6A5ACD",
  "Slate gray": "#708090",
  "Slate grey": "#708090",
  Snow: "#FFFAFA",
  "Spring green": "#00FF7F",
  "Steel blue": "#4682B4",
  Tan: "#D2B48C",
  Tomato: "#FF6347",
  Violet: "#EE82EE",
  Wheat: "#F5DEB3",
  White: "#FFFFFF",
  "White smoke": "#F5F5F5",
  Yellow: "#FFFF00",
  "Yellow green": "#9ACD32",
};

const inputColor = '#FF617E'
const findNearestColor = getNearestColor.from(baseColors)
const nearestColor = findNearestColor(inputColor)
```

Comment: [Seems about right to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UClq7.png). If you want that color to be called "yellow green", just change the name in your list of colors.

Comment: To reduce the options to the 10 colors you listed, you probably want to convert from RGB to HSB, i.e. hue, saturation, and brightness.

Comment: @user3386109 that would mean I have to check every single color. Not practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the best way to solve this problem would be to grab an annotated computer vision dataset and train a decision tree classifier. This answer is an "expert" system (scare quotes because I am anything but ☺).

[HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is not necessarily the best color system for this, but it's simple and better than RGB. Here is my proposed decision tree for the that colors you named:

1. Low saturation?

   a.  High lightness? → white

   b.  Low lightness? → black

   c.  Otherwise? → gray
2. Red hue? → red
3. Orange hue (≈ midpoint of red and yellow)?

   a.  Low lightness? → brown

   b.  Otherwise? → orange
4. Yellow hue? → yellow
5. Green hue? → green
6. Cyan hue? → blue
7. Blue hue? → blue
8. Purple hue (≈ midpoint of blue and magenta)? → purple
9. Magenta hue? → purple

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Color Classifier</title>
    <style>
      td {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="table"></table>
    <script>
      // Takes an RGB color in [0, 1]^3 and classifies it.
      function classify(red, green, blue) {
        const max = Math.max(red, green, blue);
        const min = Math.min(red, green, blue);
        const luma = 0.3 * red + 0.59 * green + 0.11 * blue;
        const chroma = max - min;
        const unsaturated = chroma < 0.15;
        if (unsaturated) {
          if (luma < 0.1) return "black";
          if (luma < 0.9) return "gray";
          return "white";
        }
        let hue_prime;
        if (red == max) {
          hue_prime = (green - blue) / chroma;
          if (hue_prime < 0) hue_prime += 6;
        } else if (green == max) {
          hue_prime = (blue - red) / chroma + 2;
        } else {
          hue_prime = (red - green) / chroma + 4;
        }
        const hue = 60 * hue_prime;
        if (hue < 17.5) return "red";
        if (hue < 50) return luma < 0.45 ? "brown" : "orange";
        if (hue < 70) return "yellow";
        if (hue < 165) return "green";
        if (hue < 255) return "blue";
        if (hue < 330) return "purple";
        return "red";
      }
      const table = document.getElementById("table");
      for (let r = 0; r <= 5; ++r) {
        const red = r / 5;
        for (let g = 0; g <= 5; ++g) {
          const green = g / 5;
          const row = table.insertRow(6 * r + g);
          for (let b = 0; b <= 5; ++b) {
            const blue = b / 5;
            const cell = row.insertCell(b);
            cell.innerText = classify(red, green, blue);
            const luma = 0.3 * red + 0.59 * green + 0.11 * blue;
            cell.style.color =
              luma < 0.5 ? "rgb(153, 153, 153)" : "rgb(102, 102, 102)";
            cell.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${255 * red}, ${255 * green}, ${
              255 * blue
            })`;
          }
          table.appendChild(row);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that is amazing!!! Learning so much!!!