# How to find if color is "close enough" to named color to be not very imperceptibly different?

Tags: javascript, math, colors

Using named colors such as those [here](https://github.com/meodai/color-names/blob/bc2f496eb1df502c97624558cc97985de894c8b7/src/colornames.csv), you might have "Abbey Pink = `#cd716b`". [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75842387/169992) answers how to get the rainbow color for any given hex color (figures out whether to call it one of "red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, brown, black, gray, white").

```
// Takes an RGB color in [0, 1]^3 and classifies it.
function classify(red, green, blue) {
  const max = Math.max(red, green, blue);
  const min = Math.min(red, green, blue);
  const luma = 0.3 * red + 0.59 * green + 0.11 * blue;
  const chroma = max - min;
  const unsaturated = chroma < 0.15;
  if (unsaturated) {
    if (luma < 0.1) return "black";
    if (luma < 0.9) return "gray";
    return "white";
  }
  let hue_prime;
  if (red == max) {
    hue_prime = (green - blue) / chroma;
    if (hue_prime < 0) hue_prime += 6;
  } else if (green == max) {
    hue_prime = (blue - red) / chroma + 2;
  } else {
    hue_prime = (red - green) / chroma + 4;
  }
  const hue = 60 * hue_prime;
  if (hue < 17.5) return "red";
  if (hue < 50) return luma < 0.45 ? "brown" : "orange";
  if (hue < 70) return "yellow";
  if (hue < 165) return "green";
  if (hue < 255) return "blue";
  if (hue < 330) return "purple";
  return "red";
}
```

How can I do the same thing, but given a map of colors like the named colors below, it will pick the closest `n` named colors, given some "fuzz factor"? Say we have a function like this:

```
function getClosestNamedColors(hex, fuzzFactor) {
  // iterate through NAMED_COLORS 
  // (or in theory any list of named colors)
  // and find the ones which are closest
  // given a radius or "fuzz factor" of some sort.
}

const NAMED_COLORS = [
  ['#f9ecfc', 'Barely Pink'],
  ['#f8e0fa', 'Be Mine'],
  ['#f8cef9', 'Scented Valentine'],
  ['#f8b5fa', 'Pink Chintz'],
  ['#e46fec', 'Springtime Bloom'],
  ['#cf4ddf', 'Fuchsia Kiss'],
  ['#a623a6', 'Hot Pink'],
  ['#f9e3f6', 'Cupid Arrow'],
  ['#eacdea', 'Cool Pink'],
  ['#d09bd0', 'Birthday Candle'],
  ['#ac6eae', 'Degas Pink'],
  ['#96548e', 'Berries And Cream'],
  ['#774172', 'Rose Garland'],
  ['#663368', 'Maroon'],
  ['#eae3ec', 'Coquette'],
  ['#e1dae7', 'Mauve Mist'],
  ['#ccc1d2', 'Pastel Violet'],
  ['#b5a8bd', 'Dark Lilac'],
  ['#877895', 'Gypsy Magic'],
  ['#685971', 'Plum Shade'],
  ['#46384a', 'Deep Aubergine'],
  ['#fbecfa', 'Ballerina Gown'],
  ['#fcdefa', 'Poetic Princess'],
  ['#fec1f6', 'Palace Rose'],
  ['#e385de', 'Foxy Pink'],
  ['#cc50c0', 'Silk Ribbon'],
  ['#a13295', 'Cran Brook'],
  ['#8b1a6f', 'Raspberry Pudding'],
  ['#fccdf4', 'Petal Bloom'],
  ['#ecacdb', 'Colonial Rose'],
  ['#e18ecd', 'Glamour'],
  ['#c05da6', 'Rosily'],
  ['#97357e', 'Mission Wildflower'],
  ['#712a5f', 'Haunting Melody'],
  ['#532448', 'Vin Rouge'],
  ['#efe9ef', 'Whimsical White'],
  ['#dfd4df', 'Brook Trout'],
  ['#d0c5cf', 'Dusky Violet'],
  ['#a99ca9', 'Heirloom Orchid'],
  ['#856e81', 'Phantom Hue'],
  ['#6a4b5f', 'Purplestone'],
  ['#482a3f', 'Deep Garnet'],
  ['#f3f2e6', 'Swiss Coffee'],
  ['#f7e9f5', 'Light Chiffon'],
  ['#fbdaf5', 'Delicate Rose'],
  ['#fbd0f0', 'Lovelight'],
  ['#fcbeee', 'Old Fashioned Pink'],
  ['#fa8bd7', 'Candy Coated'],
  ['#ec53b7', 'Watermelon Pink'],
  ['#cc2c92', 'Tropical Smoothie'],
  ['#fdc8f7', 'April Blush'],
  ['#fcaded', 'Pink Punch'],
  ['#e482cb', 'Rose Marquis'],
  ['#c045a1', 'Mulberry'],
  ['#a1287e', 'Glazed Raspberry'],
  ['#831e61', 'Cranberry Splash'],
  ['#701c52', 'Ruby Red'],
  ['#e9dfe5', 'Dreamy White'],
  ['#d2c8d0', 'French Taupe'],
  ['#c5b3be', 'Subdued Hue'],
  ['#9e8692', 'Blackberry Mocha'],
  ['#8e6d7a', 'Hickory Stick'],
  ['#654153', 'Japanese Maple'],
  ['#4f2f3d', 'Plum Raisin'],
  ['#f5eeda', 'Cottage White'],
  ['#fbe4f1', 'Sweet Nothing'],
  ['#fdc8eb', 'Fading Rose'],
  ['#fda7db', 'Ballerina Pink'],
  ['#fb85c8', 'Primrose Garden'],
  ['#f666b7', 'Bridesmaid'],
  ['#dd2f82', 'Dragon Fruit'],
  ['#b01b63', 'Cherry Wine'],
  ['#fcd6ee', 'Powdered Blush'],
  ['#f0b9dd', 'Cafe Pink'],
  ['#e7a0cd', 'Raspberry Lemonade'],
  ['#d16fb3', 'Rose Sachet'],
  ['#ad3d7b', 'Rhubarb'],
  ['#9d276b', 'Sweet Spiceberry'],
  ['#7b194b', 'Cranapple'],
  ['#eee6ee', 'Glaze White'],
  ['#dfcad6', 'Fairview Taupe'],
  ['#c8abbb', 'Rosy Tan'],
  ['#b298a6', 'Fond Memory'],
  ['#8c717e', 'Mushroom Basket'],
  ['#755866', 'Brazil Nut'],
  ['#573f4a', 'Semi Sweet'],
  ['#fae1f0', 'Strawberry Yogurt'],
  ['#fdd4ee', 'Coy Pink'],
  ['#feb1d9', 'Carnation Bloom'],
  ['#fc89c5', 'Island Coral'],
  ['#fa6aad', 'Flamingo Dream'],
  ['#d93d81', 'Italiano Rose'],
  ['#ad1545', 'Frosted Pomegranate'],
  ['#fbdaee', 'Southern Beauty'],
  ['#fabcde', 'My Fair Lady'],
  ['#f49acb', 'Hibiscus Petal'],
  ['#ea79b1', 'Fresh Pink'],
  ['#c95991', 'Rose Chintz'],
  ['#af3f72', 'Shangri La'],
  ['#8c1f46', 'Classic Cherry'],
  ['#f2e5ed', 'Patient White'],
  ['#e1cbd7', 'Royal Silk'],
  ['#c9a6ba', 'Rose Bisque'],
  ['#a3768a', 'Bedford Brown'],
  ['#8a5a71', 'Clay Ridge'],
  ['#704a5a', 'Book Binder'],
  ['#493039', 'Embarcadero'],
  ['#fce0ec', 'Silk Sheets'],
  ['#fecae2', 'Rose Sorbet'],
  ['#feabcb', 'Mixed Fruit'],
  ['#fd8db8', 'Pink Eraser'],
  ['#fb6da4', 'Cheery'],
  ['#e8325e', 'Firecracker'],
  ['#c6142e', 'Poinsettia'],
  ['#f9eaf4', 'Musical Mist'],
  ['#f6d3e5', 'Hawaiian Shell'],
  ['#efb3d0', 'Arizona Sunrise'],
  ['#eb8fb9', 'Pale Berry'],
  ['#c55b8a', 'Deep Bloom'],
  ['#b84472', 'Strawberry Rhubarb'],
  ['#8d2646', 'Regal Red'],
  ['#f3d6e2', 'Delicate Blush'],
  ['#edc7d7', 'Kashmir Pink'],
  ['#ce9bb3', 'Calico Rose'],
  ['#b5839d', 'Victorian Mauve'],
  ['#925f79', 'Mulled Wine'],
  ['#86415d', 'Gallery Red'],
  ['#662b40', 'Burnt Tile'],
  ['#fae3ee', 'Cream Rose'],
  ['#fdd8e8', 'Pale Shrimp'],
  ['#feb6d4', 'Pink Hydrangea'],
  ['#f796b8', 'Modestly Peach'],
  ['#eb6a9b', 'Candy Mix'],
  ['#e0467c', 'Coral Expression'],
  ['#aa1d38', 'Daredevil'],
  ['#fbdcea', 'Floral Linen'],
  ['#fcc1da', 'Flush Pink'],
  ['#eaa4bf', 'Rose Silk'],
  ['#e889ab', 'Strawberry Rose'],
  ['#cc5b7e', 'Lovable'],
  ['#ab3d5b', 'Pottery Red'],
  ['#812235', 'Cranberry Whip'],
  ['#f2e4ec', 'Milady'],
  ['#e5cdd7', 'Pink Water'],
  ['#c9a2b0', 'Rose Potpourri'],
  ['#b78997', 'Ponder'],
  ['#a46978', 'Rum Spice'],
  ['#793a4a', 'Boston Brick'],
  ['#5f2e37', 'Burnished Mahogany'],
  ['#fdd9e6', 'Pink Parfait'],
  ['#ffc3d8', 'Strawberry Mousse'],
  ['#ffadc6', 'Ruffles'],
  ['#fe89a6', 'Cool Melon'],
  ['#f96083', 'Youthful Coral'],
  ['#e93254', 'Lipstick'],
  ['#ae1b27', 'Red Tomato'],
  ['#fce3ec', 'Berry Cheesecake'],
  ['#fed2e0', 'Creamy Peach'],
  ['#ffb9cf', 'Coral Bells'],
  ['#f894af', 'Peach Tile'],
  ['#e56f8f', 'Mellow Coral'],
  ['#bc4665', 'Rose Wine'],
  ['#a12937', 'Farmhouse Red'],
  ['#f5e7ed', 'Reverie Pink'],
  ['#e9ccd7', 'Blush Beige'],
  ['#dbb6c1', 'Bridal Rose'],
  ['#cb9caa', 'Fondue'],
  ['#b68790', 'Brick Dust'],
  ['#915e6a', 'Gentle Doe'],
  ['#66353f', 'Leather Bound'],
  ['#fde3e9', 'Cloud Pink'],
  ['#fecfdd', 'Romantic Morn'],
  ['#ffa4b7', 'Just Blush'],
  ['#ff89a1', 'Fruit Shake'],
  ['#f65d74', 'Cool Lava'],
  ['#e93241', 'Fiery Red'],
  ['#db1e1d', 'Chili Pepper'],
  ['#fae1eb', 'Paris White'],
  ['#f8c0d3', 'Sandblast'],
  ['#eca3b5', 'Rose Linen'],
  ['#e1899c', 'Coral Serenade'],
  ['#ca5b74', 'Sahara Sun'],
  ['#b04b5f', 'Mineral Red'],
  ['#812b37', 'Roasted Pepper'],
  ['#f0e7eb', 'Italian Villa'],
  ['#e8d9de', 'Sugar Berry'],
  ['#cfb7be', 'Plymouth Notch'],
  ['#ad9497', 'Desert Willow'],
  ['#917b7e', 'Cougar'],
  ['#61484d', 'Brown Ridge'],
  ['#4d3637', 'Warm Brownie'],
  ['#f2f1e5', 'Swiss Coffee 1812'],
  ['#f4ecd9', 'Cottage White 1813'],
  ['#ece2c5', 'Navajo White 1822'],
  ['#e7e2ca', 'Antique White 1823'],
  ['#fafdf7', 'Ultra Pure White 1850'],
  ['#eef2ee', 'White 1852'],
  ['#f2f7f5', 'Frost 1857'],
  ['#f7eedc', 'Linen White 1870'],
  ['#e7e9d7', 'Off White 1873'],
  ['#f8f9f2', 'Polar Bear 1875'],
  ['#fde2e8', 'Soft Pink'],
  ['#ffcedb', 'Coral Mantle'],
  ['#ffb9c8', 'Salmon Peach'],
  ['#ff9aab', 'Duchess Rose'],
  ['#fc6c7a', 'Juicy Passionfruit'],
  ['#f44a4e', 'Wet Coral'],
  ['#e32718', 'Fire Island'],
  ['#fbe7ef', 'Frolic'],
  ['#ffc5d7', 'Full Bloom'],
  ['#ffaec3', 'Sweet Nectar'],
  ['#fc9bb4', 'Rosy Outlook'],
  ['#eb7591', 'Peony Pink'],
  ['#c03f4f', 'Red Jalapeno'],
  ['#862730', 'Briquette'],
  ['#fbedf0', 'Light Rosebeige'],
  ['#efd2dd', 'Misty Memories'],
  ['#d0adb6', 'Velveteen Crush'],
  ['#b08591', 'Warm Comfort'],
  ['#965b67', 'Brandy'],
  ['#7f484e', 'Bold Brick'],
  ['#563234', 'Mayan Red'],
  ['#fddfe6', 'Peach Cloud'],
  ['#ffcbd5', 'Coral Cream'],
  ['#ffacb5', 'Blushing Apricot'],
  ['#ff979a', 'Citrus Hill'],
  ['#ff7e7f', 'Indian Dance'],
  ['#f5635d', 'Mesa Sunrise'],
  ['#e23829', 'Fireglow'],
  ['#fbe9f0', 'Hush Pink'],
  ['#fddce4', 'Botticelli Angel'],
  ['#fdc3d1', 'Spring Song'],
  ['#f89eaf', 'Powdered Petals'],
  ['#e87077', 'Guava Jam'],
  ['#bd3d43', 'Mexican Chile'],
  ['#9b2b27', 'Rodeo Red'],
  ['#f7d9de', 'Possibly Pink'],
  ['#f4cad0', 'Salmon Tint'],
  ['#d3a4ab', 'Cinnamon Cocoa'],
  ['#be8689', 'Foxen'],
  ['#9a6462', 'Toasted Nutmeg'],
  ['#864541', 'Sequoia Grove'],
  ['#683634', 'Wine Barrel'],
  ['#fde1e4', 'Cool Cream'],
  ['#ffcdd1', 'Coral Dune'],
  ['#ffbbbe', 'Malibu Peach'],
  ['#ff9e9c', 'Sunset Strip'],
  ['#ff7864', 'Tangerine Dream'],
  ['#f84b2f', 'Aurora Orange'],
  ['#f33b0c', 'Flame'],
  ['#fae2e5', 'Angel Blush'],
  ['#facdd3', 'Demure Pink'],
  ['#f2afb5', 'Jovial'],
  ['#df9397', 'Medium Terracotta'],
  ['#d07678', 'Copperleaf'],
  ['#c1625d', 'Caribbean Coral'],
  ['#933b35', 'Firebrick'],
  ['#faeeeb', 'Bella Pink'],
  ['#efd9d9', 'Antique Pearl'],
  ['#eac9cb', 'Almond Willow'],
  ['#dcb2b3', 'Cinnamon Whip'],
  ['#c89997', 'Artifact'],
  ['#a36861', 'Chutney Brown'],
  ['#844d47', 'Brown Thrush'],
  ['#ede5c8', 'Navajo White'],
  ['#fee0db', 'Powdered Peach'],
  ['#ffd3cd', 'Friendship'],
  ['#ffb5b2', 'Sweet Apricot'],
  ['#ffa199', 'Orange Grove'],
  ['#ff826d', 'Autumn Arrival'],
  ['#fc603e', 'Harvest Pumpkin'],
  ['#f6440e', 'Electric Orange'],
  ['#fce6e7', 'White Peach'],
  ['#ffd7da', 'Peachtree'],
  ['#f5b0b0', 'Antique Cameo'],
  ['#e1958e', 'Southwest Stone'],
  ['#d57d72', 'Nectarina'],
  ['#c46a5e', 'Miami Spice'],
  ['#a65244', 'Mojave Sunset'],
  ['#f6dbde', 'Tantalizing Tan'],
  ['#f2cdd2', 'Shrimp Toast'],
  ['#deb6b4', 'Melted Ice Cream'],
  ['#cba09d', 'Sombrero Tan'],
  ['#aa7e73', 'Light Mocha'],
  ['#866058', 'Chocolate Curl'],
  ['#614c49', 'Yorkshire Brown'],
  ['#ebe4d0', 'Antique White'],
  ['#fbe4e0', 'Shell Ginger'],
  ['#ffd6d2', 'Beach Trail'],
  ['#ffc7c0', 'Apricot Lily'],
  ['#ffa792', 'Desert Sunrise'],
  ['#ff8159', 'Indian Paint Brush'],
  ['#ff621f', 'Orange Burst'],
  ['#fe550d', 'Kumquat'],
  ['#fde4df', 'Winthrop Peach'],
  ['#ffd3cd', 'Shell Coral'],
  ['#fabbac', 'Pink Beach'],
  ['#e29581', 'Pecos Spice'],
  ['#cc7761', 'Aztec Brick'],
  ['#b65b42', 'Iced Tea'],
  ['#8e3f21', 'Cinnamon Brandy'],
  ['#f5e4e4', 'Early Sunset'],
  ['#ebd0d2', 'Malibu Coast'],
  ['#d8b6b5', 'Canyon Trail'],
  ['#cfa097', 'Autumn Malt'],
  ['#bd8474', 'Suntan Glow'],
  ['#995d4b', 'Earth Tone'],
  ['#74412d', 'Florence Brown'],
  ['#fde5e3', 'Parfait'],
  ['#ffd3cb', 'Sunkissed Peach'],
  ['#ffbcac', 'Bright Citrus'],
  ['#ff9570', 'Marmalade'],
  ['#fc7d4b', 'Candied Yam (240b-5)'],
  ['#f86634', 'Orange Zest'],
  ['#e65a0e', 'Carrot Stick'],
  ['#fcebe7', 'Pink Blossom'],
  ['#fed4d1', 'Heavenly Song'],
  ['#fabbae', 'Peach Damask'],
  ['#ee9e89', 'Ceramic Glaze'],
  ['#d37c55', 'Grounded'],
  ['#c2633c', 'Chivalry Copper'],
  ['#8e4520', 'Chestnut Stallion'],
  ['#f8e2dc', 'Muffin Mix'],
  ['#f2c7bb', 'Peach Bud'],
  ['#d59f93', 'Coronado Dunes'],
  ['#c08268', 'Tiny Fawn'],
  ['#a0694d', 'Toasted Chestnut'],
  ['#885a42', 'Sable Brown'],
  ['#643e2d', 'Root Beer'],
  ['#fbefe9', 'Fine White'],
  ['#fce9e2', 'Wistful Beige'],
  ['#ffd6c9', 'Whispering Peach'],
  ['#ffaf87', 'Coral Gold'],
  ['#ff8d50', 'Orange Spice'],
  ['#fa7634', 'Poppy Glow'],
  ['#eb5509', 'Crushed Orange'],
  ['#fcf2ed', 'Bermuda Shell'],
  ['#fed7cf', 'Sugared Peach'],
  ['#ffc1ac', 'Fresco Cream'],
  ['#fca987', 'Autumn Mist'],
  ['#f68d61', 'Florida Mango'],
  ['#d56425', 'Maple Leaf'],
  ['#b24a16', 'Caramelized Orange'],
  ['#f1e7dd', 'Eurolinen'],
  ['#e0d0c2', 'Pebbled Courtyard'],
  ['#d6c4b0', 'Wild Porcini'],
  ['#b19b86', 'Stone Brown'],
  ['#b89a86', 'Stone Brown'],
  ['#8e715b', 'Fudge Bar'],
  ['#81664c', 'Pepper Spice'],
  ['#67513c', 'Melted Chocolate'],
  ['#fce9e2', 'Feather White'],
  ['#fcdfda', 'Derry Coast Sunrise'],
  ['#ffd0bf', 'Peach Beige'],
  ['#ffbfa3', 'Orange Sherbet'],
  ['#ffa173', 'Cantaloupe Slice'],
  ['#fc8647', 'Blaze Orange'],
  ['#f9752c', 'Bird Of Paradise'],
  ['#fbe1d8', 'Autumn White'],
  ['#ffd8cd', 'Salmon Creek'],
  ['#fdb088', 'Fresh Peaches'],
  ['#ef915c', 'Copper River'],
  ['#d97a3e', 'Amber Wave'],
  ['#bd6a38', 'Chai Spice'],
  ['#a65f33', 'Copper Mountain'],
  ['#fcecdf', 'Lilting Laughter'],
  ['#f0d0bc', 'Clamshell'],
  ['#e8c0aa', 'Pueblo Sand'],
  ['#d1a484', 'Sunset Beige'],
  ['#b98863', 'Applesauce Cake'],
  ['#9c7349', 'Smokey Topaz'],
  ['#7f552d', 'Caramel Latte'],
  ['#fdebde', 'Peach Fade'],
  ['#ffdbc6', 'Orange Ice'],
  ['#ffcdad', 'Luminary'],
  ['#ffb078', 'Apricot Flower'],
  ['#ff964d', 'Melon'],
  ['#f58838', 'Autumn Orange'],
  ['#db6404', 'Bonfire'],
  ['#fde8d8', 'Naive Peach'],
  ['#ffd4c4', 'Shrimp Cocktail'],
  ['#ffc4ab', 'Coral Confection'],
  ['#f8b28e', 'Brandy Butter'],
  ['#f29656', 'Adventure Orange'],
  ['#e3853f', 'Pumpkin Toast'],
  ['#c3681b', 'Fall Leaves'],
  ['#f6e6db', 'Orange Confection'],
  ['#eccfb5', 'Sandpoint'],
  ['#e1bb9a', 'Only Natural'],
  ['#c7a176', 'Peanut Butter'],
  ['#caa27f', 'Peanut Butter'],
  ['#ba9866', 'Wilmington Tan'],
  ['#9c7846', 'Fudge Truffle'],
  ['#7f5b2e', 'English Saddle'],
  ['#fdebd8', 'Creamy Orange'],
  ['#ffe4ca', 'Applecrunch'],
  ['#ffd2b0', 'Delicious Melon'],
  ['#ffc595', 'Apricot Light'],
  ['#ffa450', 'Vintage Orange'],
  ['#f8871e', 'Amber Glow'],
  ['#de7709', 'Status Bronze'],
  ['#fee3d7', 'Champagne Ice'],
  ['#f8d0bb', 'Serene Peach'],
  ['#ecb693', 'Fresh Praline'],
  ['#e49f6f', 'Caramel Sundae'],
  ['#d28c55', 'Glazed Pecan'],
  ['#c17b3d', 'Mulling Spice'],
  ['#9d5a12', 'Sesame Crunch'],
  ['#f6e9df', 'Heirloom Lace'],
  ['#ddc9b8', 'Arabian Sands'],
  ['#c6b198', 'Toasted Wheat'],
  ['#b09673', 'Burnt Almond'],
  ['#b6967a', 'Burnt Almond'],
  ['#997f58', 'New Chestnut'],
  ['#7e6849', 'Sweet Georgia Brown'],
  ['#59432f', 'Breakfast Blend'],
  ['#fbf2e3', 'Angel Food'],
  ['#feebd6', 'Country Lane'],
  ['#ffe2c7', 'Fall Straw'],
  ['#ffdab4', 'Feather Plume'],
  ['#ffc67c', 'Torchlight'],
  ['#f7a33a', 'Squash'],
  ['#f28000', 'Yam'],
  ['#fde7d6', 'Serengeti Sand'],
  ['#feddc8', 'Creamy Beige'],
  ['#fbc79f', 'Chai Latte'],
  ['#f3ac6a', 'Arizona'],
  ['#e4913f', 'Apple Crisp'],
  ['#d17921', 'Acorn'],
  ['#ba6614', 'Crispy Gingersnap'],
  ['#eee2d2', 'Weathered Sandstone'],
  ['#e3ceba', 'Oat Cake'],
  ['#d1c1a9', 'Classic Taupe'],
  ['#d5bda7', 'Classic Taupe'],
  ['#ab976d', 'Cliff Rock'],
  ['#9d8153', 'Wooden Swing'],
  ['#846e46', 'Warm Earth'],
  ['#654926', 'Wooden Cabin'],
  ['#fef2d0', 'Opal Cream'],
  ['#ffe6b3', 'Whisper Yellow'],
  ['#ffdc9d', 'Melted Butter'],
  ['#ffd189', 'Sunporch'],
  ['#ffcd7f', 'Honey Bird'],
  ['#ffae34', 'Glorious Gold'],
  ['#ff8c00', 'Goldfish'],
  ['#faecdb', 'Princess Ivory'],
  ['#fbe3cd', 'Sand Dollar White'],
  ['#facb94', 'Bagel'],
  ['#e8af6e', 'High Plateau'],
  ['#d39d55', 'Desert Caravan'],
  ['#a47526', 'Medieval Gold'],
  ['#81591a', 'Spanish Leather'],
  ['#f7e7d5', 'Biloxi'],
  ['#f0d5af', 'Calm Air'],
  ['#e0c298', 'Clair De Lune'],
  ['#bca16c', 'Almond Toast'],
  ['#a88d51', 'Brown Rabbit'],
  ['#826932', 'Highland Ridge'],
  ['#615028', 'Centaur'],
  ['#fdf4d9', 'Ivory Invitation'],
  ['#feecb6', 'Gold Buttercup'],
  ['#ffe39d', 'Manila Tint'],
  ['#ffd483', 'Cornmeal'],
  ['#ffc861', 'Spiced Butternut'],
  ['#ffb935', 'Twenty Carat'],
  ['#ffa600', 'Saffron Thread'],
  ['#fee7cd', 'Kansas Grain'],
  ['#ffe0bb', 'Orange Glow'],
  ['#fbcd96', 'Warm Cocoon'],
  ['#edba6e', 'Gold Buff'],
  ['#e4a94a', 'Sahara Shade'],
  ['#c3882b', 'Light Copper'],
  ['#a0660f', 'Mayan Gold'],
  ['#fcf2dd', 'Cancun Sand'],
  ['#f9e3c1', 'Stable Hay'],
  ['#e2c78c', 'Ripe Wheat'],
  ['#d1b16e', 'Rye'],
  ['#bc9850', 'Donegal Tweed'],
  ['#956e1c', 'Goldenrod Tea'],
  ['#7f5f17', 'Carmel Woods'],
  ['#fcf5dd', 'Eggnog'],
  ['#fef0ca', 'Provence Creme'],
  ['#feebb1', 'Cornsilk'],
  ['#fede85', 'Lemon Pound Cake'],
  ['#ffd66f', 'Zinnia Gold'],
  ['#ffcf5e', 'Mellow Yellow'],
  ['#ffb90f', 'Macaw'],
  ['#fdf0dd', 'Cotton Tail'],
  ['#ffe4bc', 'Cream Yellow'],
  ['#f7d394', 'Honey Butter'],
  ['#e6bc77', 'Arizona Tan'],
  ['#ddae53', 'Sweet Maple'],
  ['#b68832', 'Lion Mane'],
  ['#97710e', 'Victorian Gold'],
  ['#fcf0d4', 'Popcorn Ball'],
  ['#f5e2be', 'Cracked Wheat'],
  ['#deca9e', 'Riviera Sand'],
  ['#e0c6a3', 'Riviera Sand'],
  ['#d1bc8b', 'Desert Camel'],
  ['#b7a369', 'Mesa'],
  ['#907838', 'Wool Tweed'],
  ['#6c602f', 'Fig'],
  ['#fef3d2', 'Bonnie Cream'],
  ['#ffefc1', 'Frosted Lemon'],
  ['#feeca2', 'Lively Yellow'],
  ['#fee487', 'Cheerful Hue'],
  ['#fee075', 'Yellow Corn'],
  ['#ffd13d', 'Lemon Sorbet'],
  ['#ffc520', 'Sunflower'],
  ['#f8f0d4', 'Honeysuckle White'],
  ['#f7e8c6', 'Lightweight Beige'],
  ['#f5daac', 'Clam Chowder'],
  ['#e2c081', 'Warm Muffin'],
  ['#cea753', 'Campground'],
  ['#bd963f', 'Townhouse Tan'],
  ['#886b1b', 'Sconce Gold'],
  ['#f1eed4', 'Informal Ivory'],
  ['#eee2c3', 'Cornerstone'],
  ['#ebdbb3', 'Sensible Hue'],
  ['#d4c28f', 'Pebble Path'],
  ['#b39c43', 'Golden Bear'],
  ['#9a8334', 'Bristle Grass'],
  ['#7e6828', 'Nutty Brown'],
  ['#faf5d8', 'Pineapple Fizz'],
  ['#f9eebd', 'Rich Cream'],
  ['#fbe9ac', 'Song Of Summer'],
  ['#fde88f', 'Lemon Drops'],
  ['#fedf73', 'Yellow Brick Road'],
  ['#ffcc34', 'Pineapple Soda'],
  ['#ffb700', 'Empire Yellow'],
  ['#faf6e2', 'Powder Sand'],
  ['#f9e7c2', 'Havana Cream'],
  ['#f5d79e', 'Pismo Dunes'],
  ['#e9c26f', 'Honey Bear'],
  ['#d3ab42', 'Galley Gold'],
  ['#b78d1c', 'Fervent Brass'],
  ['#9f7d0d', 'Golden Green'],
  ['#faf7e1', 'Parmesan'],
  ['#f5eac7', 'Cottonseed'],
  ['#ecdcb0', 'Bavarian Cream'],
  ['#d9c389', 'Expedition Khaki'],
  ['#cfb369', 'Beachwalk'],
  ['#bc9d4d', 'Mojave Gold'],
  ['#987f33', 'Woven Basket'],
  ['#fbf9e0', 'Ruffled Clam'],
  ['#fdf5d0', 'Vanilla Milkshake'],
  ['#fff0bc', 'Pale Sunshine'],
  ['#feeca1', 'Lemon Souffle'],
  ['#fddf86', 'Straw Hat'],
  ['#fdd86b', 'Wildflower Honey'],
  ['#fec62f', 'Chickadee'],
  ['#fdf5d3', 'Downy'],
  ['#fce7b7', 'Banana Cream'],
  ['#f7d68f', 'Applesauce'],
  ['#edc56d', 'Wild Bamboo'],
  ['#d0ab45', 'French Pale Gold'],
  ['#a99035', 'Bronze Green'],
  ['#846d22', 'Cattail Brown'],
  ['#fbf5e4', 'Moonlight White'],
  ['#fbf0cd', 'Honey Moth'],
  ['#f7e5b9', 'Oklahoma Wheat'],
  ['#edd6a5', 'Quiet Veranda'],
  ['#d4c081', 'Camel'],
  ['#9e914f', 'Fossil Butte'],
  ['#73692f', 'Wild Mushroom'],
  ['#fcf7df', 'Social Butterfly'],
  ['#fdf3ca', 'Morning Sunlight'],
  ['#fdefa2', 'Banana Split'],
  ['#fde46f', 'Sweet Chamomile'],
  ['#fedd4e', 'Citrus'],
  ['#fed230', 'Flame Yellow'],
  ['#febd00', 'Center Stage'],
  ['#f6f2d3', 'Clear Yellow'],
  ['#fce7a7', 'Wickerware'],
  ['#f6e08e', 'Honey Tone'],
  ['#f4d37b', 'Warm Glow'],
  ['#e6c44b', 'Golden Chalice'],
  ['#e2ba30', 'Yellow Gold'],
  ['#b58e00', 'Brown Mustard'],
  ['#f6eecf', 'Creme Brulee'],
  ['#e7dcad', 'Castle Stone'],
  ['#dbce97', 'Winter Garden'],
  ['#c9ba66', 'Dry Sea Grass'],
  ['#b9a64b', 'Desert Moss'],
  ['#887b27', 'Raked Leaves'],
  ['#5f5528', 'Olive Shadow'],
  ['#fcf7ca', 'Moon Mist'],
  ['#fdf2a0', 'Pale Daffodil'],
  ['#fdea74', 'Bicycle Yellow'],
  ['#fde769', 'June Day'],
  ['#fde458', 'Sun Shower'],
  ['#fed92d', 'Vibrant'],
  ['#ffc800', 'Yellow Flash'],
  ['#fbf6e0', 'Lemon Pearl'],
  ['#fbf5ce', 'Custard Cream'],
  ['#f5eba7', 'Sweet Corn'],
  ['#ecdd87', 'Mustard Seed'],
]
```

The "fuzz factor" might be some sort of concept to create a radius or something like that, so it matches any hex color within some notion of a *range*. Not quite sure what that would look like though, if it's an integer or decimal number or something. I am imagining that it's not really dealing with the color *circle* necessarily, since it should take into account not just hue but lightness and saturation. But basically somehow using the named color as a point in the spectrum, and then given an input/query color, it checks all the points and if that color is within a certain boundary somehow.

Is it possible? How would you accomplish this? Basically by doing this, you could say "x given color is *close to* these named colors".

[image]

Comment: Well, if you define a distance function (whether in RGB coordinates or HSV), and then assign points to a category according to which named color is closest, then that defines a partition of the color space. The boundaries are implicit, and might be hard to characterize (or might not), but anyway, you don't need to know the boundaries to classify a new point; just compute the distance to each named color and see which one is closest. There are a few hundred named colors, right? so that will be fairly fast. My advice is try it, and only think about speeding it up if it turns out to be necessary.

Comment: see more or less duplicate QA: [RGB value base color name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37476754/2521214)

Comment: The best way (engineering point of view): you calculate Delta E (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference). JND (just noticeable difference) is often set as Delta E = 1 (and it was the initial definition). Now sometime you may use smaller numbers. For commercial quality, few delta E may be accepted. Note: Delta E works fine with small differences: do not compare delta E of the difference red to blue with the difference yellow to cyan (but if you have colours around the colour space, you should not have problem on finding small delta E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to compare 2 colors, is to convert hex to rgb and compare the RGB. working example below:

```js
const NAMED_COLORS = [ ['#f9ecfc', 'Barely Pink'], ['#f8e0fa', 'Be Mine'], ['#f8cef9', 'Scented Valentine'], ['#f8b5fa', 'Pink Chintz'], ['#e46fec', 'Springtime Bloom'], ['#cf4ddf', 'Fuchsia Kiss'], ['#a623a6', 'Hot Pink'], ['#f9e3f6', 'Cupid Arrow'], ['#eacdea', 'Cool Pink'], ['#d09bd0', 'Birthday Candle'], ['#ac6eae', 'Degas Pink'], ['#96548e', 'Berries And Cream'], ['#774172', 'Rose Garland'], ['#663368', 'Maroon'], ['#eae3ec', 'Coquette'], ['#e1dae7', 'Mauve Mist'], ['#ccc1d2', 'Pastel Violet'], ['#b5a8bd', 'Dark Lilac'], ['#877895', 'Gypsy Magic'], ['#685971', 'Plum Shade'], ['#46384a', 'Deep Aubergine'], ['#fbecfa', 'Ballerina Gown'], ['#fcdefa', 'Poetic Princess'], ['#fec1f6', 'Palace Rose'], ['#e385de', 'Foxy Pink'], ['#cc50c0', 'Silk Ribbon'], ['#a13295', 'Cran Brook'], ['#8b1a6f', 'Raspberry Pudding'], ['#fccdf4', 'Petal Bloom'], ['#ecacdb', 'Colonial Rose'], ['#e18ecd', 'Glamour'], ['#c05da6', 'Rosily'], ['#97357e', 'Mission Wildflower'], ['#712a5f', 'Haunting Melody'], ['#532448', 'Vin Rouge'], ['#efe9ef', 'Whimsical White'], ['#dfd4df', 'Brook Trout'], ['#d0c5cf', 'Dusky Violet'], ['#a99ca9', 'Heirloom Orchid'], ['#856e81', 'Phantom Hue'], ['#6a4b5f', 'Purplestone'], ['#482a3f', 'Deep Garnet'], ['#f3f2e6', 'Swiss Coffee'], ['#f7e9f5', 'Light Chiffon'], ['#fbdaf5', 'Delicate Rose'], ['#fbd0f0', 'Lovelight'], ['#fcbeee', 'Old Fashioned Pink'], ['#fa8bd7', 'Candy Coated'], ['#ec53b7', 'Watermelon Pink'], ['#cc2c92', 'Tropical Smoothie'], ['#fdc8f7', 'April Blush'], ['#fcaded', 'Pink Punch'], ['#e482cb', 'Rose Marquis'], ['#c045a1', 'Mulberry'], ['#a1287e', 'Glazed Raspberry'], ['#831e61', 'Cranberry Splash'], ['#701c52', 'Ruby Red'], ['#e9dfe5', 'Dreamy White'], ['#d2c8d0', 'French Taupe'], ['#c5b3be', 'Subdued Hue'], ['#9e8692', 'Blackberry Mocha'], ['#8e6d7a', 'Hickory Stick'], ['#654153', 'Japanese Maple'], ['#4f2f3d', 'Plum Raisin'], ['#f5eeda', 'Cottage White'], ['#fbe4f1', 'Sweet Nothing'], ['#fdc8eb', 'Fading Rose'], ['#fda7db', 'Ballerina Pink'], ['#fb85c8', 'Primrose Garden'], ['#f666b7', 'Bridesmaid'], ['#dd2f82', 'Dragon Fruit'], ['#b01b63', 'Cherry Wine'], ['#fcd6ee', 'Powdered Blush'], ['#f0b9dd', 'Cafe Pink'], ['#e7a0cd', 'Raspberry Lemonade'], ['#d16fb3', 'Rose Sachet'], ['#ad3d7b', 'Rhubarb'], ['#9d276b', 'Sweet Spiceberry'], ['#7b194b', 'Cranapple'], ['#eee6ee', 'Glaze White'], ['#dfcad6', 'Fairview Taupe'], ['#c8abbb', 'Rosy Tan'], ['#b298a6', 'Fond Memory'], ['#8c717e', 'Mushroom Basket'], ['#755866', 'Brazil Nut'], ['#573f4a', 'Semi Sweet'], ['#fae1f0', 'Strawberry Yogurt'], ['#fdd4ee', 'Coy Pink'], ['#feb1d9', 'Carnation Bloom'], ['#fc89c5', 'Island Coral'], ['#fa6aad', 'Flamingo Dream'], ['#d93d81', 'Italiano Rose'], ['#ad1545', 'Frosted Pomegranate'], ['#fbdaee', 'Southern Beauty'], ['#fabcde', 'My Fair Lady'], ['#f49acb', 'Hibiscus Petal'], ['#ea79b1', 'Fresh Pink'], ['#c95991', 'Rose Chintz'], ['#af3f72', 'Shangri La'], ['#8c1f46', 'Classic Cherry'], ['#f2e5ed', 'Patient White'], ['#e1cbd7', 'Royal Silk'], ['#c9a6ba', 'Rose Bisque'], ['#a3768a', 'Bedford Brown'], ['#8a5a71', 'Clay Ridge'], ['#704a5a', 'Book Binder'], ['#493039', 'Embarcadero'], ['#fce0ec', 'Silk Sheets'], ['#fecae2', 'Rose Sorbet'], ['#feabcb', 'Mixed Fruit'], ['#fd8db8', 'Pink Eraser'], ['#fb6da4', 'Cheery'], ['#e8325e', 'Firecracker'], ['#c6142e', 'Poinsettia'], ['#f9eaf4', 'Musical Mist'], ['#f6d3e5', 'Hawaiian Shell'], ['#efb3d0', 'Arizona Sunrise'], ['#eb8fb9', 'Pale Berry'], ['#c55b8a', 'Deep Bloom'], ['#b84472', 'Strawberry Rhubarb'], ['#8d2646', 'Regal Red'], ['#f3d6e2', 'Delicate Blush'], ['#edc7d7', 'Kashmir Pink'], ['#ce9bb3', 'Calico Rose'], ['#b5839d', 'Victorian Mauve'], ['#925f79', 'Mulled Wine'], ['#86415d', 'Gallery Red'], ['#662b40', 'Burnt Tile'], ['#fae3ee', 'Cream Rose'], ['#fdd8e8', 'Pale Shrimp'], ['#feb6d4', 'Pink Hydrangea'], ['#f796b8', 'Modestly Peach'], ['#eb6a9b', 'Candy Mix'], ['#e0467c', 'Coral Expression'], ['#aa1d38', 'Daredevil'], ['#fbdcea', 'Floral Linen'], ['#fcc1da', 'Flush Pink'], ['#eaa4bf', 'Rose Silk'], ['#e889ab', 'Strawberry Rose'], ['#cc5b7e', 'Lovable'], ['#ab3d5b', 'Pottery Red'], ['#812235', 'Cranberry Whip'], ['#f2e4ec', 'Milady'], ['#e5cdd7', 'Pink Water'], ['#c9a2b0', 'Rose Potpourri'], ['#b78997', 'Ponder'], ['#a46978', 'Rum Spice'], ['#793a4a', 'Boston Brick'], ['#5f2e37', 'Burnished Mahogany'], ['#fdd9e6', 'Pink Parfait'], ['#ffc3d8', 'Strawberry Mousse'], ['#ffadc6', 'Ruffles'], ['#fe89a6', 'Cool Melon'], ['#f96083', 'Youthful Coral'], ['#e93254', 'Lipstick'], ['#ae1b27', 'Red Tomato'], ['#fce3ec', 'Berry Cheesecake'], ['#fed2e0', 'Creamy Peach'], ['#ffb9cf', 'Coral Bells'], ['#f894af', 'Peach Tile'], ['#e56f8f', 'Mellow Coral'], ['#bc4665', 'Rose Wine'], ['#a12937', 'Farmhouse Red'], ['#f5e7ed', 'Reverie Pink'], ['#e9ccd7', 'Blush Beige'], ['#dbb6c1', 'Bridal Rose'], ['#cb9caa', 'Fondue'], ['#b68790', 'Brick Dust'], ['#915e6a', 'Gentle Doe'], ['#66353f', 'Leather Bound'], ['#fde3e9', 'Cloud Pink'], ['#fecfdd', 'Romantic Morn'], ['#ffa4b7', 'Just Blush'], ['#ff89a1', 'Fruit Shake'], ['#f65d74', 'Cool Lava'], ['#e93241', 'Fiery Red'], ['#db1e1d', 'Chili Pepper'], ['#fae1eb', 'Paris White'], ['#f8c0d3', 'Sandblast'], ['#eca3b5', 'Rose Linen'], ['#e1899c', 'Coral Serenade'], ['#ca5b74', 'Sahara Sun'], ['#b04b5f', 'Mineral Red'], ['#812b37', 'Roasted Pepper'], ['#f0e7eb', 'Italian Villa'], ['#e8d9de', 'Sugar Berry'], ['#cfb7be', 'Plymouth Notch'], ['#ad9497', 'Desert Willow'], ['#917b7e', 'Cougar'], ['#61484d', 'Brown Ridge'], ['#4d3637', 'Warm Brownie'], ['#f2f1e5', 'Swiss Coffee 1812'], ['#f4ecd9', 'Cottage White 1813'], ['#ece2c5', 'Navajo White 1822'], ['#e7e2ca', 'Antique White 1823'], ['#fafdf7', 'Ultra Pure White 1850'], ['#eef2ee', 'White 1852'], ['#f2f7f5', 'Frost 1857'], ['#f7eedc', 'Linen White 1870'], ['#e7e9d7', 'Off White 1873'], ['#f8f9f2', 'Polar Bear 1875'], ['#fde2e8', 'Soft Pink'], ['#ffcedb', 'Coral Mantle'], ['#ffb9c8', 'Salmon Peach'], ['#ff9aab', 'Duchess Rose'], ['#fc6c7a', 'Juicy Passionfruit'], ['#f44a4e', 'Wet Coral'], ['#e32718', 'Fire Island'], ['#fbe7ef', 'Frolic'], ['#ffc5d7', 'Full Bloom'], ['#ffaec3', 'Sweet Nectar'], ['#fc9bb4', 'Rosy Outlook'], ['#eb7591', 'Peony Pink'], ['#c03f4f', 'Red Jalapeno'], ['#862730', 'Briquette'], ['#fbedf0', 'Light Rosebeige'], ['#efd2dd', 'Misty Memories'], ['#d0adb6', 'Velveteen Crush'], ['#b08591', 'Warm Comfort'], ['#965b67', 'Brandy'], ['#7f484e', 'Bold Brick'], ['#563234', 'Mayan Red'], ['#fddfe6', 'Peach Cloud'], ['#ffcbd5', 'Coral Cream'], ['#ffacb5', 'Blushing Apricot'], ['#ff979a', 'Citrus Hill'], ['#ff7e7f', 'Indian Dance'], ['#f5635d', 'Mesa Sunrise'], ['#e23829', 'Fireglow'], ['#fbe9f0', 'Hush Pink'], ['#fddce4', 'Botticelli Angel'], ['#fdc3d1', 'Spring Song'], ['#f89eaf', 'Powdered Petals'], ['#e87077', 'Guava Jam'], ['#bd3d43', 'Mexican Chile'], ['#9b2b27', 'Rodeo Red'], ['#f7d9de', 'Possibly Pink'], ['#f4cad0', 'Salmon Tint'], ['#d3a4ab', 'Cinnamon Cocoa'], ['#be8689', 'Foxen'], ['#9a6462', 'Toasted Nutmeg'], ['#864541', 'Sequoia Grove'], ['#683634', 'Wine Barrel'], ['#fde1e4', 'Cool Cream'], ['#ffcdd1', 'Coral Dune'], ['#ffbbbe', 'Malibu Peach'], ['#ff9e9c', 'Sunset Strip'], ['#ff7864', 'Tangerine Dream'], ['#f84b2f', 'Aurora Orange'], ['#f33b0c', 'Flame'], ['#fae2e5', 'Angel Blush'], ['#facdd3', 'Demure Pink'], ['#f2afb5', 'Jovial'], ['#df9397', 'Medium Terracotta'], ['#d07678', 'Copperleaf'], ['#c1625d', 'Caribbean Coral'], ['#933b35', 'Firebrick'], ['#faeeeb', 'Bella Pink'], ['#efd9d9', 'Antique Pearl'], ['#eac9cb', 'Almond Willow'], ['#dcb2b3', 'Cinnamon Whip'], ['#c89997', 'Artifact'], ['#a36861', 'Chutney Brown'], ['#844d47', 'Brown Thrush'], ['#ede5c8', 'Navajo White'], ['#fee0db', 'Powdered Peach'], ['#ffd3cd', 'Friendship'], ['#ffb5b2', 'Sweet Apricot'], ['#ffa199', 'Orange Grove'], ['#ff826d', 'Autumn Arrival'], ['#fc603e', 'Harvest Pumpkin'], ['#f6440e', 'Electric Orange'], ['#fce6e7', 'White Peach'], ['#ffd7da', 'Peachtree'], ['#f5b0b0', 'Antique Cameo'], ['#e1958e', 'Southwest Stone'], ['#d57d72', 'Nectarina'], ['#c46a5e', 'Miami Spice'], ['#a65244', 'Mojave Sunset'], ['#f6dbde', 'Tantalizing Tan'], ['#f2cdd2', 'Shrimp Toast'], ['#deb6b4', 'Melted Ice Cream'], ['#cba09d', 'Sombrero Tan'], ['#aa7e73', 'Light Mocha'], ['#866058', 'Chocolate Curl'], ['#614c49', 'Yorkshire Brown'], ['#ebe4d0', 'Antique White'], ['#fbe4e0', 'Shell Ginger'], ['#ffd6d2', 'Beach Trail'], ['#ffc7c0', 'Apricot Lily'], ['#ffa792', 'Desert Sunrise'], ['#ff8159', 'Indian Paint Brush'], ['#ff621f', 'Orange Burst'], ['#fe550d', 'Kumquat'], ['#fde4df', 'Winthrop Peach'], ['#ffd3cd', 'Shell Coral'], ['#fabbac', 'Pink Beach'], ['#e29581', 'Pecos Spice'], ['#cc7761', 'Aztec Brick'], ['#b65b42', 'Iced Tea'], ['#8e3f21', 'Cinnamon Brandy'], ['#f5e4e4', 'Early Sunset'], ['#ebd0d2', 'Malibu Coast'], ['#d8b6b5', 'Canyon Trail'], ['#cfa097', 'Autumn Malt'], ['#bd8474', 'Suntan Glow'], ['#995d4b', 'Earth Tone'], ['#74412d', 'Florence Brown'], ['#fde5e3', 'Parfait'], ['#ffd3cb', 'Sunkissed Peach'], ['#ffbcac', 'Bright Citrus'], ['#ff9570', 'Marmalade'], ['#fc7d4b', 'Candied Yam (240b-5)'], ['#f86634', 'Orange Zest'], ['#e65a0e', 'Carrot Stick'], ['#fcebe7', 'Pink Blossom'], ['#fed4d1', 'Heavenly Song'], ['#fabbae', 'Peach Damask'], ['#ee9e89', 'Ceramic Glaze'], ['#d37c55', 'Grounded'], ['#c2633c', 'Chivalry Copper'], ['#8e4520', 'Chestnut Stallion'], ['#f8e2dc', 'Muffin Mix'], ['#f2c7bb', 'Peach Bud'], ['#d59f93', 'Coronado Dunes'], ['#c08268', 'Tiny Fawn'], ['#a0694d', 'Toasted Chestnut'], ['#885a42', 'Sable Brown'], ['#643e2d', 'Root Beer'], ['#fbefe9', 'Fine White'], ['#fce9e2', 'Wistful Beige'], ['#ffd6c9', 'Whispering Peach'], ['#ffaf87', 'Coral Gold'], ['#ff8d50', 'Orange Spice'], ['#fa7634', 'Poppy Glow'], ['#eb5509', 'Crushed Orange'], ['#fcf2ed', 'Bermuda Shell'], ['#fed7cf', 'Sugared Peach'], ['#ffc1ac', 'Fresco Cream'], ['#fca987', 'Autumn Mist'], ['#f68d61', 'Florida Mango'], ['#d56425', 'Maple Leaf'], ['#b24a16', 'Caramelized Orange'], ['#f1e7dd', 'Eurolinen'], ['#e0d0c2', 'Pebbled Courtyard'], ['#d6c4b0', 'Wild Porcini'], ['#b19b86', 'Stone Brown'], ['#b89a86', 'Stone Brown'], ['#8e715b', 'Fudge Bar'], ['#81664c', 'Pepper Spice'], ['#67513c', 'Melted Chocolate'], ['#fce9e2', 'Feather White'], ['#fcdfda', 'Derry Coast Sunrise'], ['#ffd0bf', 'Peach Beige'], ['#ffbfa3', 'Orange Sherbet'], ['#ffa173', 'Cantaloupe Slice'], ['#fc8647', 'Blaze Orange'], ['#f9752c', 'Bird Of Paradise'], ['#fbe1d8', 'Autumn White'], ['#ffd8cd', 'Salmon Creek'], ['#fdb088', 'Fresh Peaches'], ['#ef915c', 'Copper River'], ['#d97a3e', 'Amber Wave'], ['#bd6a38', 'Chai Spice'], ['#a65f33', 'Copper Mountain'], ['#fcecdf', 'Lilting Laughter'], ['#f0d0bc', 'Clamshell'], ['#e8c0aa', 'Pueblo Sand'], ['#d1a484', 'Sunset Beige'], ['#b98863', 'Applesauce Cake'], ['#9c7349', 'Smokey Topaz'], ['#7f552d', 'Caramel Latte'], ['#fdebde', 'Peach Fade'], ['#ffdbc6', 'Orange Ice'], ['#ffcdad', 'Luminary'], ['#ffb078', 'Apricot Flower'], ['#ff964d', 'Melon'], ['#f58838', 'Autumn Orange'], ['#db6404', 'Bonfire'], ['#fde8d8', 'Naive Peach'], ['#ffd4c4', 'Shrimp Cocktail'], ['#ffc4ab', 'Coral Confection'], ['#f8b28e', 'Brandy Butter'], ['#f29656', 'Adventure Orange'], ['#e3853f', 'Pumpkin Toast'], ['#c3681b', 'Fall Leaves'], ['#f6e6db', 'Orange Confection'], ['#eccfb5', 'Sandpoint'], ['#e1bb9a', 'Only Natural'], ['#c7a176', 'Peanut Butter'], ['#caa27f', 'Peanut Butter'], ['#ba9866', 'Wilmington Tan'], ['#9c7846', 'Fudge Truffle'], ['#7f5b2e', 'English Saddle'], ['#fdebd8', 'Creamy Orange'], ['#ffe4ca', 'Applecrunch'], ['#ffd2b0', 'Delicious Melon'], ['#ffc595', 'Apricot Light'], ['#ffa450', 'Vintage Orange'], ['#f8871e', 'Amber Glow'], ['#de7709', 'Status Bronze'], ['#fee3d7', 'Champagne Ice'], ['#f8d0bb', 'Serene Peach'], ['#ecb693', 'Fresh Praline'], ['#e49f6f', 'Caramel Sundae'], ['#d28c55', 'Glazed Pecan'], ['#c17b3d', 'Mulling Spice'], ['#9d5a12', 'Sesame Crunch'], ['#f6e9df', 'Heirloom Lace'], ['#ddc9b8', 'Arabian Sands'], ['#c6b198', 'Toasted Wheat'], ['#b09673', 'Burnt Almond'], ['#b6967a', 'Burnt Almond'], ['#997f58', 'New Chestnut'], ['#7e6849', 'Sweet Georgia Brown'], ['#59432f', 'Breakfast Blend'], ['#fbf2e3', 'Angel Food'], ['#feebd6', 'Country Lane'], ['#ffe2c7', 'Fall Straw'], ['#ffdab4', 'Feather Plume'], ['#ffc67c', 'Torchlight'], ['#f7a33a', 'Squash'], ['#f28000', 'Yam'], ['#fde7d6', 'Serengeti Sand'], ['#feddc8', 'Creamy Beige'], ['#fbc79f', 'Chai Latte'], ['#f3ac6a', 'Arizona'], ['#e4913f', 'Apple Crisp'], ['#d17921', 'Acorn'], ['#ba6614', 'Crispy Gingersnap'], ['#eee2d2', 'Weathered Sandstone'], ['#e3ceba', 'Oat Cake'], ['#d1c1a9', 'Classic Taupe'], ['#d5bda7', 'Classic Taupe'], ['#ab976d', 'Cliff Rock'], ['#9d8153', 'Wooden Swing'], ['#846e46', 'Warm Earth'], ['#654926', 'Wooden Cabin'], ['#fef2d0', 'Opal Cream'], ['#ffe6b3', 'Whisper Yellow'], ['#ffdc9d', 'Melted Butter'], ['#ffd189', 'Sunporch'], ['#ffcd7f', 'Honey Bird'], ['#ffae34', 'Glorious Gold'], ['#ff8c00', 'Goldfish'], ['#faecdb', 'Princess Ivory'], ['#fbe3cd', 'Sand Dollar White'], ['#facb94', 'Bagel'], ['#e8af6e', 'High Plateau'], ['#d39d55', 'Desert Caravan'], ['#a47526', 'Medieval Gold'], ['#81591a', 'Spanish Leather'], ['#f7e7d5', 'Biloxi'], ['#f0d5af', 'Calm Air'], ['#e0c298', 'Clair De Lune'], ['#bca16c', 'Almond Toast'], ['#a88d51', 'Brown Rabbit'], ['#826932', 'Highland Ridge'], ['#615028', 'Centaur'], ['#fdf4d9', 'Ivory Invitation'], ['#feecb6', 'Gold Buttercup'], ['#ffe39d', 'Manila Tint'], ['#ffd483', 'Cornmeal'], ['#ffc861', 'Spiced Butternut'], ['#ffb935', 'Twenty Carat'], ['#ffa600', 'Saffron Thread'], ['#fee7cd', 'Kansas Grain'], ['#ffe0bb', 'Orange Glow'], ['#fbcd96', 'Warm Cocoon'], ['#edba6e', 'Gold Buff'], ['#e4a94a', 'Sahara Shade'], ['#c3882b', 'Light Copper'], ['#a0660f', 'Mayan Gold'], ['#fcf2dd', 'Cancun Sand'], ['#f9e3c1', 'Stable Hay'], ['#e2c78c', 'Ripe Wheat'], ['#d1b16e', 'Rye'], ['#bc9850', 'Donegal Tweed'], ['#956e1c', 'Goldenrod Tea'], ['#7f5f17', 'Carmel Woods'], ['#fcf5dd', 'Eggnog'], ['#fef0ca', 'Provence Creme'], ['#feebb1', 'Cornsilk'], ['#fede85', 'Lemon Pound Cake'], ['#ffd66f', 'Zinnia Gold'], ['#ffcf5e', 'Mellow Yellow'], ['#ffb90f', 'Macaw'], ['#fdf0dd', 'Cotton Tail'], ['#ffe4bc', 'Cream Yellow'], ['#f7d394', 'Honey Butter'], ['#e6bc77', 'Arizona Tan'], ['#ddae53', 'Sweet Maple'], ['#b68832', 'Lion Mane'], ['#97710e', 'Victorian Gold'], ['#fcf0d4', 'Popcorn Ball'], ['#f5e2be', 'Cracked Wheat'], ['#deca9e', 'Riviera Sand'], ['#e0c6a3', 'Riviera Sand'], ['#d1bc8b', 'Desert Camel'], ['#b7a369', 'Mesa'], ['#907838', 'Wool Tweed'], ['#6c602f', 'Fig'], ['#fef3d2', 'Bonnie Cream'], ['#ffefc1', 'Frosted Lemon'], ['#feeca2', 'Lively Yellow'], ['#fee487', 'Cheerful Hue'], ['#fee075', 'Yellow Corn'], ['#ffd13d', 'Lemon Sorbet'], ['#ffc520', 'Sunflower'], ['#f8f0d4', 'Honeysuckle White'], ['#f7e8c6', 'Lightweight Beige'], ['#f5daac', 'Clam Chowder'], ['#e2c081', 'Warm Muffin'], ['#cea753', 'Campground'], ['#bd963f', 'Townhouse Tan'], ['#886b1b', 'Sconce Gold'], ['#f1eed4', 'Informal Ivory'], ['#eee2c3', 'Cornerstone'], ['#ebdbb3', 'Sensible Hue'], ['#d4c28f', 'Pebble Path'], ['#b39c43', 'Golden Bear'], ['#9a8334', 'Bristle Grass'], ['#7e6828', 'Nutty Brown'], ['#faf5d8', 'Pineapple Fizz'], ['#f9eebd', 'Rich Cream'], ['#fbe9ac', 'Song Of Summer'], ['#fde88f', 'Lemon Drops'], ['#fedf73', 'Yellow Brick Road'], ['#ffcc34', 'Pineapple Soda'], ['#ffb700', 'Empire Yellow'], ['#faf6e2', 'Powder Sand'], ['#f9e7c2', 'Havana Cream'], ['#f5d79e', 'Pismo Dunes'], ['#e9c26f', 'Honey Bear'], ['#d3ab42', 'Galley Gold'], ['#b78d1c', 'Fervent Brass'], ['#9f7d0d', 'Golden Green'], ['#faf7e1', 'Parmesan'], ['#f5eac7', 'Cottonseed'], ['#ecdcb0', 'Bavarian Cream'], ['#d9c389', 'Expedition Khaki'], ['#cfb369', 'Beachwalk'], ['#bc9d4d', 'Mojave Gold'], ['#987f33', 'Woven Basket'], ['#fbf9e0', 'Ruffled Clam'], ['#fdf5d0', 'Vanilla Milkshake'], ['#fff0bc', 'Pale Sunshine'], ['#feeca1', 'Lemon Souffle'], ['#fddf86', 'Straw Hat'], ['#fdd86b', 'Wildflower Honey'], ['#fec62f', 'Chickadee'], ['#fdf5d3', 'Downy'], ['#fce7b7', 'Banana Cream'], ['#f7d68f', 'Applesauce'], ['#edc56d', 'Wild Bamboo'], ['#d0ab45', 'French Pale Gold'], ['#a99035', 'Bronze Green'], ['#846d22', 'Cattail Brown'], ['#fbf5e4', 'Moonlight White'], ['#fbf0cd', 'Honey Moth'], ['#f7e5b9', 'Oklahoma Wheat'], ['#edd6a5', 'Quiet Veranda'], ['#d4c081', 'Camel'], ['#9e914f', 'Fossil Butte'], ['#73692f', 'Wild Mushroom'], ['#fcf7df', 'Social Butterfly'], ['#fdf3ca', 'Morning Sunlight'], ['#fdefa2', 'Banana Split'], ['#fde46f', 'Sweet Chamomile'], ['#fedd4e', 'Citrus'], ['#fed230', 'Flame Yellow'], ['#febd00', 'Center Stage'], ['#f6f2d3', 'Clear Yellow'], ['#fce7a7', 'Wickerware'], ['#f6e08e', 'Honey Tone'], ['#f4d37b', 'Warm Glow'], ['#e6c44b', 'Golden Chalice'], ['#e2ba30', 'Yellow Gold'], ['#b58e00', 'Brown Mustard'], ['#f6eecf', 'Creme Brulee'], ['#e7dcad', 'Castle Stone'], ['#dbce97', 'Winter Garden'], ['#c9ba66', 'Dry Sea Grass'], ['#b9a64b', 'Desert Moss'], ['#887b27', 'Raked Leaves'], ['#5f5528', 'Olive Shadow'], ['#fcf7ca', 'Moon Mist'], ['#fdf2a0', 'Pale Daffodil'], ['#fdea74', 'Bicycle Yellow'], ['#fde769', 'June Day'], ['#fde458', 'Sun Shower'], ['#fed92d', 'Vibrant'], ['#ffc800', 'Yellow Flash'], ['#fbf6e0', 'Lemon Pearl'], ['#fbf5ce', 'Custard Cream'], ['#f5eba7', 'Sweet Corn'], ['#ecdd87', 'Mustard Seed'], ];

const colorLabel = document.querySelector('#title');
const colorBG = document.querySelector('#color-bg');

function hexToRGB(hex) {
  const [r, g, b] = hex.match(/[0-9a-fA-f]{2}/g).map(part => parseInt(part, 16));
  return {r, g, b};
}

function getSimilarityScore(rgb1, rgb2) {
  return Math.pow(rgb1.r-rgb2.r, 2)+Math.pow(rgb1.g-rgb2.g, 2)+Math.pow(rgb1.b-rgb2.b, 2);
}

function pickClosestColor(hex) {
  const rgb = hexToRGB(hex);
  let bestColor = NAMED_COLORS[0];
  let bestScore = Infinity;
  
  for(const color of NAMED_COLORS) {
    const score = getSimilarityScore(rgb, hexToRGB(color[0]));
    if(score < bestScore) {
      bestColor = color;
      bestScore = score;
    }
  }
  
  colorLabel.innerText = `Similar Color: ${bestColor[1]} (${bestColor[0]})`;
  colorBG.style.background = bestColor[0];
}
```

```css
#title {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#color-bg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="color" onChange="pickClosestColor(this.value)"/>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="color-bg"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: What is the range of the similarity score min/max? That way I can pick all that have a score greater than x (or less than x, whatever is a better match).

Comment: The range is 0 to (255**2)*3 (=195075).
However if you interested in the value itself and not only comparation, you may want to get sqrt of the score. distance function is sqrt of sum of squares, I just not took it because I only interested to know if its greater or smaller, but real value will be the root, which is `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rgb1.r-rgb2.r, 2)+Math.pow(rgb1.g-rgb2.g, 2)+Math.pow(rgb1.b-rgb2.b, 2))` and then range will be 0 to 441.673